# Promise.all in Node.js not blocking in function call using map and async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I wrote a small module to talk to Zookeeper to obtain a list of service endpoints.
Everything work fine except for the part that return that list of endpoint. In the module, I expose a function that should return an array of endpoints obtain by calling getData (from module node-zookeeper-client) as many time as there's children in a specific path on Zookeeper. I tried to combine array map and Promise.all to call the getData x times but my function return before the Promise.all resolve ending with an "undefined" variable on the caller side. Here my code snippet:

**zookeeper.js**

```
...
const getData = (entry) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.getData(
      "/application/agent/" + entry,
      function (error, data, stat) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log('getData resolve %s',data.toString('utf8'));
          resolve(data.toString('utf8'));
        }
      });
  });
};
...
function agentsEndpoint() {
  console.log('Begin agentsEndpoint...');
  var requests = agentList.map(getData);
  console.log('requests: %s', requests);
  var results = Promise.all(requests);
  console.log('results: %s', results);
  results.then((endpoints) => {
    return endpoints;
  });
  console.log('...agentsEndpoint return.');
}

module.exports = { agentsEndpoint };
```

**main.js**

```
...
const zk = require('./zookeeper.js');
zk.client.connect();

setInterval(listEndpoints,5000, zk);
function listEndpoints(zk) {
  console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s',zk.agentsEndpoint());
}
...
```

**And here the console output:**

```
Begin agentsEndpoint...
requests: [object Promise],[object Promise]
results: [object Promise]
...agentsEndpoint return.
Calling agentsEndpoint: undefined
getData resolve 10.0.0.8/getEndpoint
getData resolve 10.0.0.10/getEndpoint
```

My expected behavior was that the function should have wait at the line *results.then((endpoints) => {* for the resulting Promise to resolve but as you can see in the console output, it resolve much later.

What I am missing here?!?!

Comment: `agentsEndpoint` doesn’t return anything. You should return the promise from `Promise.all()`

Comment: and then rewrite how you call `agentsEndpoint` because it will return a Promise (i.e. use `async`/`await` or regular `.then` on the promise it returns) - i.e. `async function listEndpoints(zk) {
  console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s', await zk.agentsEndpoint());
}`

Comment: the fact that *Promise.all is not blocking* is obvious, since Promises are inherently asynchronous and therefore do not block

Comment: @JaromandaX I re-wrote the code as your suggest and it work! Thx. But can I "isolate" the caller (main.js) from this async/await? I want my function too simply return an array of endpoints. Thx again!

Comment: asynchrony can not be isolated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of the problem you are having is that `agentsEndpoint` is doing asynchronous things, but it is not returning anything. In order to know *when* the async parts of the function are done you need to return a promise from this function too, just like `getData`. Then the caller will receive the promise and can use it when it resolves. The basic idea without the `console.logs` will look like this:

In zookeeper.js ==>

```
const agentsEndpoint = () => Promise.all(agentList.map(getData));
```

In main.js ==>

```
function listEndpoints(zk) {
    zk.agentsEndpoint()
    .then(elements => console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s', elements))
  }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it look syntactically correct but a got this error : const agentsEndpoint = (agentList) => Promise.all(agentList.map(getData));
                                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @SteveS. the function wants you to pass in the `agentList` sorry, I left that out of the call. Edited to fix.

Comment: Humm, now it stumble on agentList :  zk.agentsEndpoint(agentList).then(elements => console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s', elements)) ReferenceError: agentList is not defined. agentList is defined in zookeeper.js not in main.js

Comment: You're using `agentList` in your code, but it's not defined in the example you posted. I'm assuming the somewhere in the code you have a reference to it. `zk.agentsEndpoint` needs that reference.

Comment: agentList is defined in the module zookeeper.js. It hold the list of agent registed in the service on Zookeeper. The main.js module call the exported method agentsEndpoint.

Comment: Ahh, you can just alter the functions not to take the argument then. See edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s',zk.agentsEndpoint());
```

You function don't return anything.

```
function agentsEndpoint() {
  ...
  console.log('...agentsEndpoint return.');
}
```

So `Calling agentsEndpoint: undefined` is valid answer.

You should  work with `agentsEndpoint` as async.

You may use callback, promise or async/await for it.

See example:

```
function agentsEndpoint() {
    console.log('Begin agentsEndpoint...');
    var requests = agentList.map(getData);
    console.log('requests: %s', requests);
    var results = Promise.all(requests);
    console.log('results: %s', results);
    return results;
}

function listEndpoints(zk) {
 zk.agentsEndpoint().then(endpoints => console.log('Calling agentsEndpoint: %s', endpoints);
}
```

Comment: Wrapping `Promise.all` in a promise is an anti pattern. `Promise.all` already returns a promise.

Comment: Yeh, Thanks. I had not target for write code for topic starter. It is was just copy-paste.